# Why did new dependencies appear after migrating from maven to gradle

Tags: java, maven, gradle

The app in my work is a maven application with a pom file inherited from a parent pom file. I followed the migration doc and did a scan for both maven and gradle build. But I noticed some dependency has a few additional child dependencies included in the gradle build? These dependencies are not existing and failed my build. How to fix it?

Here is a comparison between the maven build report and the gradle build report.

[image]

The top one is from gradle, the bottom one is from maven.

Update:
here is the transitive dependencies that failed my gradle build. It seems `<Optional>true` does not work in gradle.
[image]

Comment: Are you sure there were not exclusions defined in in Maven for these "additional" dependencies? Could you show the whole POM?

Comment: The gradle file is generated by the maven migration plugin provided by gradle. I did not change anything manually.

Comment: But maybe this migration plugin is not working 100% correctly? Couldn't you just show us the POM?

Answer (score 0):

Gradle and Maven resolve dependency conflicts differently. The same raw dependency graph can therefore produce a different, final and resolved, dependency graph when both are used with default settings.

[here is the section of the gradle docs that talk about the differences between how the two systems work.](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_resolution.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Gradle: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/26110

Optional dependencies generally are treated correctly. But it seems Gradle does not ignore the surrounding spaces in the tag content while Maven ignores them.

The question is, where you have the POM from. I cannot find the mentioned dependency in any public Maven repository. It seems like this POM was somehow hand-crafted and not built by a tool, because any automatically generated POM should not have those spaces there and would thus be treated properly.

So if this is a POM you manually created, you could easily fix it by removing those spaces.